# TabView blank when trying to display json data via onAppear()

Tags: swift, swiftui

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1en4JyW3XSI&t=1s) to call data from my API. I veered off a bit and instead used TabView to show a "home page" where data loads in the first tab. It "works" in the sense that if I navigate to another tab and go back to the home tab the data appears. When I open the app though, the tab is blank. I initially declare `posts` as an empty array, by why is `onAppear()` not populating it?

Here's the view that is supposed to be displaying my data

```
struct DiscoverView: View {
    @ObservedObject var discoverPosts: DiscoverPosts
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(alignment: .center){
                    ForEach(self.discoverPosts.posts) { post in
                        HStack{
                            DiscoverList(isModal : false,displayName : post.displayName,id : post.id,likes : post.likes,owner : post.owner,avatar : post.avatar,author_id : post.author_id,icebreaker : post.icebreaker,answer : post.answer,mediaLink : post.mediaLink,songURL : post.songURL,type : post.type,liked: post.liked)
                        }
                        .padding(10)
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear(){
                // self.discoverPosts.getPosts()
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle("Discover")
        }
    }
}
```

here is my `discoverPosts()`

```
class discoverPosts : ObservableObject {
    @State var posts : [Post] = []
    func getPosts(completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> ()){
        let feedURL = "URL"
        guard let url = URL(string: feedURL) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            let posts = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.posts = posts
                completion(posts)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

my ConventView.swift that shows the TabView. I believe the issue could be the hierarchy

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        Home()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct Home : View {
    
    @State var show = false
    @State var status = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "status") as? Bool ?? false
    
    var body: some View{
            VStack{
                
                if self.status{
                    
                    TabView {
                        DiscoverView(discoverPosts: DiscoverPosts())
                            .tabItem(){
                                Image(systemName: "person")
                                .font(.system(size:20))
                            }
                            .tag(1)
                        InboxView(offsetLine: IndexSet.Element())
                            .tabItem(){
                                Image(systemName: "message")
                                .font(.system(size: 20))
                            }
                            .tag(2)
                        ProfileView()
                            .tabItem(){
                                Image(systemName: "person")
                                .font(.system(size: 20))
                            }
                            .tag(3)
                    }
                    .accentColor(Color.purple)
                    .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
                }
                else{
                    
                    ZStack{
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: SignUp(show: self.$show), isActive: self.$show) {
                            
                            Text("")
                        }
                        .hidden()
                        
                        Login(show: self.$show)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .onAppear {
                
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("status"), object: nil, queue: .main) { (_) in
                    
                    self.status = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "status") as? Bool ?? false
                }
            }
    }
}
```

For those that experience this, You can throw `Text("").frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)` at the bottom of `ScrollView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ObservableObject to:

```
class DiscoverPosts: ObservableObject { // make Types capitalised
    @Published var posts: [Post] = [] // <- replace @State with @Published

    init() {
        getPosts()
    }

    func getPosts() { // <- no need for completion handler, update `self.posts`
        let feedURL = "URL"
        guard let url = URL(string: feedURL) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
            let posts = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.posts = posts
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

and use it in your view like this:

```
struct DiscoverView: View {
    @ObservedObject var discoverPosts: DiscoverPosts // declare only

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ...
        }
        //.onAppear { // <- remove onAppear
        //    self.discoverPosts.getPosts()
        //}
    }
}
```

You also need to pass `DiscoverPosts` to `DiscoverView` from `Home` view:

```
DiscoverView(discoverPosts: DiscoverPosts())
```

Note that if you previously accessed `self.posts` in your view, you will now need to access `self.discoverPosts.posts`

Comment: I've edited my post to include my discoverPosts() and made some edits following your lead. The home tab still displays blank when the app first loads, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting this error `Variable used within its own initial value` on the line for `@ObservedObject var discoverPosts = DiscoverPosts()`

Comment: @MarkusProctor Note that I changed `class DiscoverPosts` and it's now capitalised. The good practice in Swift is to use capitalised names for types.

Comment: Yup, just noticed. Still blank X( I'll edit my original post to go up a layer in the code.

Comment: I appreciate your help with this. It's still blank on the initial load. I still have to change tabs.

Comment: @MarkusProctor Looking at your TabView, try replacing `.id(1)` with `.tag(1)`

Comment: updated. still blank. I've modified my original post adding `tag()` to the tab  item itself

Comment: this must be a bug with `ScrollView` because I do not have this problem if I use `List`

Comment: It was working the entire time. Because the `ScrollView` was initially rendered with a size of 0x0. I needed to add something like `Text("").frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)` so that when the post data filled in, the canvas was stretched.

Comment: @MarkusProctor You can try using `List` instead of `ScrollView` - this should resolve all your issues.